# Android to PC communication via internet connection

Tags: android, server, client, client-server

I'm trying to send a command from an android device to a pc program through the internet. A basic example is I press a button on my android device and the pc receives a command to do something.

The android and pc are not on the same network and the only way to communicate is through the internet. I have looked at sending sms's or emails, but this won't work for the system I want to develop.

I have no idea how to implement this communication. Are there any possible sources, examples or tutorials I can use to just find a starting point?

Comment: this is wrong place to ask for `sources, examples or tutorials`. Basically, you can send a command from the client (android device) to server (your PC) only if your PC has a real IP address. If it does not - then you have to put some web server in the middle, and then both your pc and your Android become clients. One sends the command for another to web server. The other periodically asks the web server if it has any commands

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked into this. Do I need to buy a domain name if I want to try and create my own web server.

Comment: you may use the IP address for that